# Perform multiple Identity actions in a transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, transactions, asp.net-core-identity

I want to perform multiple Identity-related actions in a transaction. There is [some guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) in the docs for EF in general, but not for Identity in particular.

This approach is used in many SO posts:

```cs
using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
try
{
  var result1 = await _userManager.Foo();
  if (!result1.Succeeded) throw new Exception("Could not foo.");

  var result2 = await _userManager.Bar();
  if (!result2.Succeeded) throw new Exception("Could not bar.");

  await transaction.CommitAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  _logger.LogError(e, "Something bad happened, but changes were rolled back.");
  // ...handle error
}
```

Ordinarily, without Identity, if execution enters the catch block then the transaction is not committed and is disposed (and thus automatically rolled back).

But:

- Identity calls `SaveChanges` after every action, so at face value it seems like the rollback would accomplish nothing.
- I don't know whether `_context` is the same one used internally by `_userManager`? I think the context is registered by default as scoped (per request), so I assume that within an ASP.NET Core HTTP request, the same context will be used by both Identity and my code.

*Is that correct?*

#### UPDATE:

I can't find definitive documentation for these issues, and am uncomfortable relying on internal implementation details for something so critical. <strike>So I opened a [docs issue](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/32143) on the repo, asking for official guidance. Please upvote it if this concerns you too.</strike>

Update: they closed that docs request without proper consideration. So I opened another on the [main repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54855). Please upvote that.

Comment: You can easily test whether both operations are being performed in that transaction performing both and then rolling back the transaction. If you see the changes in the database then it must have been a different context. You could also modify the service methods to take a context as an argument and then check whether you got the same context as the service is already using. You need to do all you can first.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes good points. From my hacking into it, and checking the source, it seems it does use the same context as me, but it bothers me that something so basic is not officially documented anywhere, and I must rely on internal implementation details. If something like this breaks, the result would be catastrophic given it's auth-related. I think I'll ask on the repo for them to update the docs. Thanks!

Comment: I asked on the [docs repo](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/32143) for them to add official guidance. My approach until then is to assume it's the same instance in both Identity and client code, but that is a massive assumption that relies on an implementation detail which is liable to change, and would cause auth-related problems. Basically, ultra risky code. If you also need this info, please upvote that issue for them to prioritise it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, it's the same instance of `DbContext` for all subsequent services within a request, you may already faced this error `The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for { 'ID'} is already being tracked`, this happens if you try to get same entity twice in the same scope (of course without using `AsNotTracking`).

Internal `Transaction` in EF Core is about how you call the `SaveChanges` method, EF opens a transaction when you want to write something into the database like insert/update/delete, when you call the `SaveChanges` method EF will wrap all operations in a transaction so if any exception raised then they will be rolled back.

But in your scenario, it depends on what you're doing in the Foo and Bar methods, imagine **without** using Transaction: if you are writing something in those methods means for each you call SaveChanges separately so if the Foo ran successfully and Bar failed, EF can't roll back the Foo changes because the transaction is already committed but Bar changes will roll back.

Based on the docs you already shared:

```cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
//....

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The `ApplicationDbContext`is registered by calling `AddDbContext` but `AddEntityFrameworkStores` method is only referring to it because it needs to generate migration and seeding data. another point here is Transactions is applying on the database side, so because of having one DbContext instance per request and pointing to the same database (connectionString) then still I would say your approach is right and safe.

Worth checking the code here as well: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs

Comment: Thanks! I agree with everything you wrote, but the question is about Identity specifically. You nailed the problem on the head in the third paragraph.  Behind the scenes Identity performs a SaveChanges for any action you ask of it. The issue is whether it uses the same DbContext I'm using. I assume it does (but don't know for sure). And regardless, I don't want to rely on an implementation detail which could change tomorrow. I was hoping this is documented officially somewhere, or there is official guidance, but I can't find anything.

Comment: @lonix I made some changes to the answer and also upvote your github issue, hope .NET team clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. In ASP.NET Core, the default behavior is to register the `DbContext` as scoped, meaning that within the same HTTP request, the same instance of the context will be shared across all components that participate in that request's scope, including the `_userManager`.

So, in your code, both `_context` and `_userManager` will typically share the same instance of the `DbContext` within the same HTTP request. Therefore, using a transaction to perform multiple actions involving both `_context` and `_userManager` should work as expected.

Your code looks fine in terms of using transactions to perform multiple identity-related actions within a single unit of work. However, there are a couple of points to consider for improvement:

1. **Error Handling**: Your error handling approach is good, as it ensures that if any of the actions fail, the transaction is rolled back. However, throwing a generic `Exception` may not provide enough information about what exactly went wrong. It's a good practice to use more specific exception types or to provide more context about the error.
2. **Async/Await Pattern**: You're using async/await pattern correctly, which is good for performance and scalability in ASP.NET Core applications.
3. **Logging**: You're logging errors, which is important for diagnosing issues. However, make sure to log enough information to facilitate troubleshooting.
4. **Dependency Injection**: Ensure that `_userManager` and `_context` are properly registered and injected into your class. It seems you're doing it correctly, but it's worth mentioning.

Overall, your approach seems solid for performing multiple identity-related actions within a transaction in ASP.NET Core. Just make sure to handle errors effectively and provide enough logging and context for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find out for certain whether Identity (specifically `UserManager<T>`) is using the same instance of `DbContext` as I do. This topic is not covered anywhere in the docs (that I could find), and there's no guidance. Like you wrote above, one would "typically" expect it to share the instance, but that isn't definitive.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT, isn't?